# What is the meaning of "than" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "than" in the following sentence,

> "I wish we could," said Dot.
>
> "Can we look for one tomorrow?"
>
> "Not tomorrow," said Dot's daddy.
>
> "It would take more time **than** I will have"

?

Does "It would take more time than I will have" mean " It would take more time in order that I will have" ?

Does "than" in the sentence mean "in order that (in order to)" ?

Comment: *Than* is not *then*. You might try a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sentence, **than** has the normal meaning ([Oxford dictionary meaning 1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/than)) of introducing the second item of a comparison. Here is a simpler example:

> John gets paid more than me

Pay is what's being compared: **John** is the first item in the comparison, and **me** is the second item.

> It would take more time than I will have

What we are comparing is time: the first item is the amount of time that it will take to look for whatever-it-is, and the second item is the amount time that Dot's father has available tomorrow.